# Validate input before pressing button in Java

Tags: java, joptionpane, numberformatexception

I have a dialog box that creates itself and is supposed to check the input of the user. At the moment I can get it validate an empty input and to parse the user input correctly when it is an Integer, however I keep get NumberFormatException when validating with a String. Adding a try, catch did stop the JVM from crashing but the input is then null.

```
public void initDialog() {
    dPanel = new JPanel();
    dPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(dPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JLabel invalidInput = new JLabel("");
    String[] options = {"OK"};
    dPanel.add(new JLabel("Game default target is 101, enter a number below to change it"));
    dPanel.add(new JLabel("Leave blank to start with the default"));
    dPanel.add(invalidInput);
    JTextField text = new JTextField("");
    text.requestFocusInWindow();
    dPanel.add(text);

    int changeGameTarget = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, dPanel, "Dice Game", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

    dialogHandler(changeGameTarget, text, invalidInput);

    text.setText("");
}
```

Dialog handling method

```
   public boolean dialogHandler(int op, JTextField text, JLabel nonDigit) {

    String s = text.getText();

    try {
        if (op == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                target = 101;
            } else {
                target = Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        nonDigit.setText("This is not a number");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: so when the input is not an integeter, you want the user to input something else?

Comment: Yeah, I want the user to have to re enter an input that is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the *Try-Catch* in the parse as an *if-else* and change method to boolean, so you can make it a loop in the main.

```
public boolean dialogHandler(int op, JTextField text, JLabel nonDigit) {

  String s = text.getText();

  if (op == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
      return false; // If the text is empty we return false for the flag.
    } else {
      try {
        target = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true; // If parse was succesful, we return true for the flag.
      } catch (Exception e) { 
        return false; // If the exception happened, return false for the flag.
      }
    }
  } else if (op == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Then we change main:

```
boolean flag;
do {
  int changeGameTarget = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, dPanel, "Dice Game", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
  flag = dialogHandler(changeGameTarget, text, invalidInput);
} while (!flag);
```

Comment: Your main method edit can't see the changeGameTarget while it's in the int

Comment: Can you try placing it in a variable and try again? I'll edit.

Comment: This works perfectly, I hope you don't mind, but I just edited your code so that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay solving your problem should be quite simple:

First, you change your method signature to

`public boolean dialogHandler(int op, JTextField text, JLabel nonDigit)`

This allows you to return wether the input was good (`true`) or bad (`false`).
Then you just surround your method with a `try-catch` block and catch the `NumberFormatException`. In case an Exception is caught, return `false`, otherwise return `true`.

Then you only have to write that when the result of the method is false, the user has to input something else.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example as to how I can have the user input again? I've update my question with the boolean signatrure method